# Isometry between $l^p$ and $L^p$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider $p\in[1,\infty)$ and the operator $T:l^p\rightarrow L^p([0,\infty))$:
$$
Tx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\chi_{[n-1,n]} \qquad\forall\,x\in(x_1,x_2,\ldots,)\in l^p
$$
Prove that $T$ is an isometry. My idea was to start with the definitions of the norms:
$$
||x||_{l^p}^p=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|^p=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_0^\infty|\chi_{[n-1,n]}x_n|^p\,d\mu = (\cdots) = \int_0^\infty|\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}x_n\chi_{[n-1,n]}|^pd\mu=||Tx||_{L^p}^p
$$
I miss the central part and I'm not sure it is possibile to "connect" the norms in this way. I tried to think about some theorem about limits-integrals exchange but I didn't find anything. Or is it better to prove both the inequatilities between the norms?

Answer (score 1):

Note the disjointness of the supports in the sum.  It breaks apart nicely.

$$||x||_{l^p}^p
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|^p
= \sum_{n\ge 1}|x_n|^p\int_{n-1}^n d\mu 
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_0^\infty|\chi_{[n-1,n]}x_n|^p\,d\mu 
=||Tx||_{L^p}^p
$$

Comment: But isn't missing a passage? Where is $\int(serie)^p$?

Comment: It is still missing... look the last = before $||Tx||_{L^p}^p$